# Why is my array being read as null? What am I missing?

Tags: arrays, powershell

I am working on PowerShell script that will check server services. I keep getting a "Cannot index into a null array."

The error references the second if statement "if ($select_string_result.Line[$select_string_result.Line.Length-1] -eq '1')"

The object type of "$select_string_result" is displayed as Array and the txt file has data but the script will not process through it.

The "Line" property of the array records as null and the "Length" is recorded as 0.

```
$filepathserver = 'Path'
$filepathlocal = 'Path'

function Get-Timestamp
{
    return Get-Date -Format "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt"
}

function refresh-data
{
    # Pulls Services and Services Status
    $orionData = Get-SwisData $swis "SELECT ComponentID, StatusDescription FROM Orion.APM.Component"

    # Sends output to a txt file
    $orionData | Out-File "$filepathlocal\All_App_Services.txt"
}

function check-status($select_string_result)
{
    if ($select_string_result.Line -isnot [system.array])
    {
        if ($select_string_result.Line[$select_string_result.Line.Length-1] -eq '1')
        {
            return 100
        }
        else
        {
            return 0
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $sum = 0.0
        $add = 100.0/$select_string_result.Length

        foreach ($match in $select_string_result)
        {
            if ($match.Line[$match.Line.Length-1] -eq '1')
            {
                $sum += $add
            }
        }
        if ($sum -lt 100) {$sum = 0} # this line collapses the values in to either 0 or 100
        $sum = [int][Math]::Ceiling($sum)
        return $sum
    }
}

function main
{
    refresh-data
    # Filters for Application specific Services
    $f = @("94944 ", "94945 ", "94951 ", "94946 ", "94942 ", "94948 ", "94949 ", "94950 ", "94943 ", "94947 ", "94952 ", "94953 ")

    $AppServices = Get-Content "Path" | Select-String $f
    $AppServices | Set-Content "Path"

    #Removes leading spaces from array
    (Get-Content "$filepathlocal\File.txt") -replace "Up","1" | % {$_.trim()} | Out-File "$filepathlocal\File.txt"

    $AppServices = Get-Content "$filepathlocal\File.txt"
    $AppServices.GetType()

    # Writes status of each group to .txt file
    $logfile= "$filepathserver\ServicesStatus.txt"
    $t = Get-Timestamp
    $v = check-status $AppServices
    $s = "$t|Application-Services|$v"
    $s | Out-File $logfile -Append -Encoding "UTF8"
    $s
}

main
```

Comment: Can you explain what the first `if` statement is doing? `if ($select_string_result.Line -isnot [system.array])
` seems to say that the thing you are trying to index into is not an array. That could be the source of your problem.

Comment: It is checking that an array is being passed, if not it moves on to the else statement and does math on the end of each line in the text file.

Since the second if statement is being called, the variable is being seen as an array. Or I assume it is.

I also call a "variable.GetType" that reports the variable as an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$select_string_result.Line` resolves to `$null` because the array of strings that you get from `Get-Content` does not have a `Line` property, so the `if` statement should look more like:

```
if($select_string_result[$select_string_result.Length - 1] -eq '1') { ... }
```

PowerShell also allows you to address the last index with just `-1`, allowing us to simplify the statement as:

```
if($select_string_result[-1] -eq '1') { ... }
```

That being said, rather than attempting to check whether the parameter passed to a function is an array or not, you'd want to declare the parameter an array in the first place and then use a `foreach` loop over it:

```
function check-status([string[]]$select_string_result)
{
    $sum = 0.0
    $add = 100.0/$select_string_result.Length

    foreach ($match in $select_string_result)
    {
        if ($match[-1] -eq '1')
        {
            $sum += $add
        }
    }
    if ($sum -lt 100) {$sum = 0} # this line collapses the values in to either 0 or 100
    $sum = [int][Math]::Ceiling($sum)
    return $sum
}
```

much nice, way less code.

Now, instead of attempting to index into the string, I'd suggest using the `-like` wildcard operator or the `-match` regex operator to check whether each string ends with `1`:

```
if ($match -like '*1')
{
    $sum += $add
}
```

Since `$sum` is always exactly `100`, or otherwise gets reset to `0`, the call to `[Math]::Ceiling()` is redundant and can be removed:

```
function check-status([string[]]$select_string_result)
{
    $sum = 0.0
    $add = 100.0/$select_string_result.Length

    foreach ($match in $select_string_result)
    {
        if ($match -like '*1')
        {
            $sum += $add
        }
    }
    if ($sum -lt 100) {$sum = 0} # this line collapses the values in to either 0 or 100
    return $sum
}
```

If you look carefully at the function as implemented, you'll notice that the only case in which `100` is returned is when *all* strings in `$select_string_result` end in `1`.

We can easily test for this by using the `-like` operator directly on our input array, it will act as a filter operator:

```
function check-status([string[]]$select_string_result)
{
    if(@($select_string_result -like '*1').Count -eq $select_string_result.Count)
    {
        $sum = 100
    }
    else 
    {
        $sum = 0
    }
    return $sum
}
```

Now, another way of asserting that all strings in the array end in `1`, is to simply test whether *no* string does *not* end in `1`:

```
function check-status([string[]]$select_string_result)
{
    if(@($select_string_result -notlike '*1'))
    {
        $sum = 0
    }
    else 
    {
        $sum = 100
    }
    return $sum
}
```

Now all we need to do is shine it up a bit, like change `check` to a more appropriate verb and we've got a much nicer, short or powershell-idiomatic function :-)

```
function Measure-StatusValue
{
    param(
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [string[]]$StatusStrings
    )

    if(@($StatusStrings -notlike '*1'))
    {
        return 0
    }

    return 100
}
```